# INNER JOIN MAX condition type

Tags: r, inner-join

I have two dataframes:

```
info
Fname  Lname
Henry      H
 Rose      R
Jacob      T
 John      O
 Fred      Y
Simon      S
  Gay      T
```

And

```
students
Fname  Lname  Age  Height  Subject Result
Henry      H   12      15 Math;Sci      P
 Rose      R   11      18 Math;Sci      P
Jacob      T   11      15 Math;Sci      P
Henry      H   11      14 Math;Sci      P
 John      O   12      13 Math;Sci      P
 John      O   13      16 Math;Sci      F
 Fred      Y   11      16      Sci      P
Simon      S   12      10 Eng;Math      P
  Gay      T   12      11 Math;Sci      F
 Rose      R   15      18 Math;Sci      P
 Fred      Y   12      16 Math;Sci      P
```

I want to do a JOIN and get all the names from info and find its relevant metadata from students. But only pick the one with the **highest age** (when Fname and LName are equal). My output should look like:

```
Final
Fname Lname Age Height  Subject Result
Henry     H  12     15 Math;Sci      P
 Rose     R  15     18 Math;Sci      P
Jacob     T  11     15 Math;Sci      P
 John     O  13     16 Math;Sci      F
 Fred     Y  12     16 Math;Sci      P
Simon     S  12     10 Eng;Math      P
  Gay     T  12     11 Math;Sci      F
```

I have tried `sqldf` but with no luck yet. I'm just not able to get the identifiers correctly. Is there any other way I can get my output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perhaps less than elegant way, using base `R`.

Now, merge the frames on the names (although there is little point in doing so here in this example; it is really just a list of names already in the `students` frame).

```
merged_df <- merge(students,info,by=c("Fname","Lname"))
```

Finally, aggregate, here just on names. You could add any categorical or factor variables.

```
merged_df_max <-aggregate(
                merged_df[c('Age','Height')], 
                by=list(Fname = merged_df$Fname,
                        Lname = merged_df$Lname), 
                FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)

## add back details to the merged df
result <- merge(merged_df_max,students,by=c("Fname","Lname","Age","Height"))
```

To create data.frame from file,

```
## load data
lines <-"
Fname,Lname,Age,Height,Subject,Result
Henry,H,12,15,Math;Sci,P
Rose,R,11,18,Math;Sci,P
Jacob,T,11,15,Math;Sci,P
Henry,H,11,14,Math;Sci,P
John,O,12,13,Math;Sci,P
John,O,13,16,Math;Sci,F
Fred,Y,11,16,Sci,P
Simon,S,12,10,Eng;Math,P
Gay,T,12,11,Math;Sci,F
Rose,R,15,18,Math;Sci,P
Fred,Y,12,16,Math;Sci,P
"

lines2 <-"
Fname,Lname
Henry,H
Rose,R
Jacob,T
John,O
Fred,Y
Simon,S
Gay,T
"

con <- textConnection(lines)
students <- read.csv(con,sep=',')
con2 <- textConnection(lines2)
info <- read.csv(con2,sep=',')
close(con)
close(con2)
```

Comment: Don't use `attach` please.

Comment: @Pascal sorry! Wont happen again.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

info %>% left_join(students) %>%
    group_by(Fname, Lname) %>%
    filter(Age == max(Age))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Fname, Lname, max(Age) Age, Height, Subject, Result 
       from info left join students using (Fname, Lname)
       group by Fname, Lname")
```

We used a left join in case there are students in `info` with no data in `students`.  In the question the students in `info` and `students` are the same so we could have omitted the word `left` in the query and still have gotten the same result.  Also note that because the exact same set of students appears in both `info` and `students` we would not need to use `info` at all.  This is the same as the last query except for the `from` line but gives the same answer with the data provided:

```
sqldf("select Fname, Lname, max(Age) Age, Height, Subject, Result 
       from students
       group by Fname, Lname")
```

**Note:**  For reproducibility the following constructs the `info` and `student` data frames.  Please provide this yourself in the future when asking questions on SO.

```
Lines_info <- "
Fname  Lname
Henry      H
 Rose      R
Jacob      T
 John      O
 Fred      Y
Simon      S
  Gay      T
"
Lines_students <- "
Fname  Lname  Age  Height  Subject Result
Henry      H   12      15 Math;Sci      P
 Rose      R   11      18 Math;Sci      P
Jacob      T   11      15 Math;Sci      P
Henry      H   11      14 Math;Sci      P
 John      O   12      13 Math;Sci      P
 John      O   13      16 Math;Sci      F
 Fred      Y   11      16      Sci      P
Simon      S   12      10 Eng;Math      P
  Gay      T   12      11 Math;Sci      F
 Rose      R   15      18 Math;Sci      P
 Fred      Y   12      16 Math;Sci      P
"

info <- read.table(text = Lines_info, header = TRUE)
students <- read.table(text = Lines_students, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will remember your advice.